# asp.net mvc 3 unobtrusive client side validation not working in ie

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-validate, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-1.6

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery.Validate/1.7/jQuery.Validate.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I am using data annotations to display the error message. In Firefox its working fine, but in IE its not displaying the error message in the client side.
from the below link [JQuery 1.6 $('form').validate() not working in IE7 & IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909260/jquery-1-6-form-validate-not-working-in-ie7-ie8), I came to see that

> Jquery Validate does not currently work with jQuery 1.6 in IE6, IE7,
>   and IE8.

I am using jquery UI autocomplete,Datepicker in my project. So if i change the jquery version from 1.6.2 to jquery 1.5.2 my validation works fine, but my autocomplete starts failing.

how to solve this? any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery.validate 1.8.1 is release for 2001 may to be resolve this problem for ie, I integrated with my MVC 3 project with client side validation and it works perfect for me.